# preg_match in PHP (XML extract)

Tags: php, preg-match

```
152124687951<?xml version="1.0"><culo>Amazing</culo></Document>65464614
```

I have to extract only the XML code inside.
I could have more of XML code and I need to extract it one by one. Its starts always with </Document>. Someone could help me? Thanks...

Comment: Does your input always look like `/[0-9]+(XML)[0-9]+/`? Also there is not opened tag Document at the end.

Comment: Is not important if XML is validated or not. The first and the last set of code could be numeric or alphanumeric too...

Comment: you mean always **end** with `</Document>` ?

Comment: IIUC, use regexp `/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/`, you'll get three matches, second of which will be your XML.

Comment: I need to save only <?xml ... </Document>

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, but with your solution the output is 152124687951

Comment: If always end with </Document> http://www.regexr.com/39p9q

Comment: Does your string contain several "xml" documents?

Comment: @Armeice Try it now: http://www.regexr.com/39pa6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use substr and strops to  get all the matches you need.
It's true that regex performs worst than other solutions. So, if performance is important to you, consider other alternatives.

In other hand, performance may not be an issue (side project, background process, etc) so regex is a clean way to do the job.

From my understading you have something like:

```
152124687951<?xml version="1.0"><culo>Amazing</culo></Document>65464614
abc<?xml version="1.0"><culo>Amazing</culo></Document>abc
abc<?xml version="1.0"><culo>Amazing</culo></Document>abc
abc<?xml version="1.0"><culo>Amazing</culo></Document>abc
```

And you want to extract all the xml inside this.
So a perfect working regex will be:

```
@\<\?xml.+Document\>@
```

You can see a live result here: http://www.regexr.com/39p9q
Or you could test it online: https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html

At the end, the `$matches` variable will have something like (depends on the flaw you use in `preg_match_all`:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '<?xml version="1.0"><culo>Amazing</culo></Document>',
    1 => '<?xml version="1.0"><culo>Amazing</culo></Document>',
  ),
)
```

So you could just iterate over it and that's all.

About performance, here is a quick test:

http://3v4l.org/B1t7h/perf#tabs

Comment: If you're going to post a performance test, at least compare the performance with other solutions -- e.g. `strpos`, `substr`, etc. The results mean nothing without something to compare them to.

Comment: Yes of course. Provide a test using strpos and substr that does the same. None of the other answers work with multiple xml... and I don't have the time to make it, so provide the code and I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that `preg_match` may not be the best approach here given the context you have described. Perhaps the following might serve your requirement more efficiently, with the supplied XML sample is held in *$sXml* prior to execution:

```
$sXml = substr( $sXml, strpos( $sXml, '<?xml' ));
$sXml = substr( $sXml, 0,
  strpos( $sXml, '</Document>' ) + strlen( '</Document>' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string is large and contains many datas after and before the "XML" part, a good way (performant) consists to find the start and end offsets with `strpos` and to extract the substring after, example:

```
$start = strpos($str, '<?xml ');
$end = strpos(strrev($str), '>tnemucoD/<');

if ($start !== false && $end !== false)
    $result = substr($str, $start, - $end);
```

If your string is not too big you can use preg_match:

```
if (preg_match('~\Q<?xml \E.+?</Document>~s', $str, $m))
    $result = $m[0];
```

`\Q....\E` allows to write special characters (in a regex meaning) without to have to escape them. (useful to write a literal string without asking questions.). But note that in the present example, only `?` needs to be escaped.